# Does routing affect a socket with a bound source address?

Tags: linux, networking, router, ip, routes

Let's say I have two network interfaces:

- `eth0` with address `10.0.0.1`
- `eth1` with address `192.168.0.1`

Using `route` or `ip route add` I have set it to route:

- All addresses to `eth0`
- `1.2.3.4` only to `eth1`

So packets to `1.2.3.4` should be routed to `eth1`, and everything else to `eth0`.

I then create a UDP socket and use `bind()` to set its local address to `192.168.0.1`. Then I send a packet to `1.2.3.4`.

Will it be be sent over `eth1` per the routing table or `eth0` because it is bound to that IP address? I tried, and it seems to be sent on `eth1`.

Is there a way I can force a socket to use `eth0`, which has a valid route to the destination, but not the most specific rule? I know about SO_BINDTODEVICE, but prefer to avoid using interface names in C code.

Comment: Please explain your application, i.e.: what is the *reason* you'd like to send a packet to eth0? Routing works as follows: Pick the most specific route and send it to that interface. If there are equally specific routes, pick one at random (which usually is bad). `default` ("all addresses") is the least specific route. You can't change this from an application, but you can do all sorts of funny stuff with iptables. But depending on your application, you probably don't need to.

Comment: Actually your examination is wrong in the first place. You did a configuration so that `1.2.3.4` goes to `192.168.0.1` and then you said I create a socket and bound it to `192.168.0.1` and I sent packet to `1.2.3.4`!. So in either way it should sent on `eth1`. You probably intended to bind your socket to `10.0.0.1` and ask this question...

Answer (score 2):

For sockets if you want the the Kernel and its routing table to pick the best interface for you using any available port you don't have to call `bind()` before sending datagram socket.

If you do bind a socket, it will be bound to a network device with that specific IP address. But does it make sense if packet can't reach destination address from that network device?

Comment: Actually that is not I observed recently. I bound the socket to `192.168.0.1 (eth1)` and send the packet to `8.8.8.8` and expected the Kernel to send the packet via `eth1`. In fact Linux kernel sent a packet (IP=192.168.0.1) via `eth0`, which is really weird.